# How to focus on new child item added to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have and ExpandableListView which I dynamically add child items when the return key is pressed on the last item. When this occurs when the screen runs out of space my new item is added however it does not get focused on, and is not seen b/c the keyboard is visible. I want to scroll down and make the last item to be in focus.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to modify my previous answer b/c I found some issues with trying to scroll up. I created a new method

```
 public static int getScreenHeight(){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    return size.y;
}
```

Then in side of my code where I add a new child item to the list I have this:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 listView.smoothScrollToPosition(Utility.getScreenHeight());
```

I only call the code above if the item is the last item of the list. There is a slight delay when typing before the cursor catches up, approx. 2 sec. Anyway hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After reading several posts and trying several shared ideas this is the solution I figured out for my issue.

In my ExpandableListAdapter which extends the BaseExpandableListAdapter I added in the getChildView() the following:

```
//this line is added after I add the new child 
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
expandableListView.smoothScrollToPosition(this.getChildrenCount(groupPosition));
//the 'this' is the adapter
```